# IB API - get data on position that close

Tags: programming, data, interactive-brokers, order-handling

I am trying to implement a few new features for my trading system. My plan for now is to initially buy the stocks i wants (using Vwap) and when the order has closed (bought all the quantity) I want to collect 3 parameters(ticker name,avg price, quantity bought),of the order (in order to place TP\SL commands). Neither reqPosition nor orderStatus or reqExecutions seems to return all of them and I couldn't figure how how to do it yet. Any insight on my small problem would be great!

Thank a lot in advance!

Comment: If you are using Python, you may want to have a look at the ib-insync library.  It's a wrapper for IB's native Python API.  It has much better documentation and plenty of code examples and notebooks: https://ib-insync.readthedocs.io/readme.html

Comment: @amdopt Totally agree.  I find the IB API to be abstract and difficult to use.  Amir Ariely: ib_insync makes it easy to retrieve the portfolio and positions and will give you the three parameters you have an interest in.

Comment: Thank you both a lot! I am trying to change my code to ib_insync. Could you please tell me what it the function that returns the ticker'avg price and quantity when the position is fulfilled?